# Placing a WebView below ListView with images in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application In which i have a `ListView` with images.I want that `WebView` should be placed below the categories..

The screenshot of the view is

http://www.imageupload.org/?d=B6D3C3E61

Can anyone tell how should I place a `WebView` in the space below categories?

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative layout. place webview below of listview

Try with the following xml approach

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview001"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
Deepak